# Background Color form Container Div displaying in Main Content area

Tags: html, css

I need some help to hide the background color of my container div.

The main content area is structure in such a way that the article tags stack on top of each other and then after that the footer should take up whatever space is left.

I have tried to get rid of the space between the article tag and the footer while still keeping the margin. In order words I want to get rid of the blue line while.

Can someone give me a hint of how to achieve this?

```css
#container {
    background-color: #004bb8;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 960px;
}


/*------Header-----*/
header {
    background-color: lightsalmon;
    border-bottom: solid #65ff09 2px;
}

h1, h2 {
    font-family: "Impact";
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: darkred;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}

#image-container {
    float: left;
    width: 46%;
    margin: 0 1% 0 1%;
    padding: 1%;
}

#sitename{
    float: left;
    width: 46%;
    margin: 0 1% 0 1%;
    padding: 8% 1% 1% 1%;
}

header::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: left;
}

header img {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header h1 {
    font-family: "Abel", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: #f9db00;
    
}

header h2 {
    font-family: "Abel", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: #ff2a86;
}



/*-------navigation------*/
nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: 
}
nav ul li {}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: .3em;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: #004bb8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

nav ul li.active a {
    background-color: #b8005c;    
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #f9db00;
    color: #323C40
}



/*-------content------*/
#content {
    min-height: 5em;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#content article {
    margin: 0 2%;
}

#content article.News, #content article.Tweets {
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
} 

article.News h2, article.Tweets h2 {
    background-color: darkgray;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
article.News h2 {background-color: #004bb8;}
article.Tweets h2 {background-color: #b8005c;} 

article.News h3, article.Tweets h3 {
    padding: 0.5em 0 0 1%;
    font-size: 1.0em;
}

article.News h3 {color: #004bb8;}
article.Tweets h3 {color: #b8005c;}

article.News p, article.Tweets p {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    line-height: 120%;

}
#contents article.Tweets::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: left;
}

/*-------footer------*/
footer {
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #111;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.6em;
}


/*---------IMAGES------------*/

figure.w100 {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

figure.w33 {
    width: 96%;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin: 0.3em 0 0.3em 2%; 
}
figure.w33 img {
    width: 100%;
}

figure.w100 img {
    width: 100%;

}

#content figcaption {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    color: #777;
    padding: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="container">
                <header>
                    <div id="image-container">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
                    </div>
                    <div id="sitename">
                        <h1>Responsive Design</h1>
                        <h2>Don't Settle for Less</h2>
                    </div>                   
                
                </header>

                <!--------Page Navigation Links -->
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Desktop Work Around</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Phone-Default</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tablet Enhancement</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reset CSS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                 <!--------Page Content -->
                <div id="content">
                    
                    <figure class="w100">
                        <img src="img/lake.jpeg" alt="lake">
                    </figure>
                    <article>
                        <h2> Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                        <figure class="w33">
                            <img src="img/car.jpeg" alt="car">
                            <figcaption> what i wish to drive when i get super rich</figcaption>
                        </figure>
                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, posuere erat quis tellus, pede non maecenas convallis dapibus ut, ipsum arcu facilisi nunc mollis eu risus, fermentum volutpat maecenas convallis etiam, et eget ut aliquet phasellus sagittis metus. Nulla vel wisi a eu in. Diam sociis eros.         Aliquet vitae commodo ante, rutrum praesent odio urna pellentesque. Metus viverra volutpat etiam lorem nesciunt, sapien pellentesque, massa nec. Nec congue aliquam a lobortis sed, dui imperdiet vestibulum magnis aenean sed sit, dignissim sem sodales.
                        </p>
                    </article>

                    <div class="row">

                        <article class="News">
                            <h2>News</h2>
                            <h3>A list apart finally goes responsive</h3>
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, posuere erat quis tellus, pede non maecenas convallis dapibus ut, ipsum arcu facilisi nunc mollis eu risus, fermentum volutpat maecenas convallis etiam, et eget ut aliquet phasellus sagittis metus. Nulla vel wisi a eu in. Diam sociis eros.         Aliquet vitae commodo ante, rutrum praesent odio urna pellentesque. Metus viverra volutpat etiam lorem nesciunt, sapien pellentesque, massa nec. Nec congue aliquam a lobortis sed, dui imperdiet vestibulum magnis aenean sed sit, dignissim sem sodales.
                            </p>

                            <h3>A list apart finally goes responsive</h3>
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, posuere erat quis tellus, pede non maecenas convallis dapibus ut, ipsum arcu facilisi nunc mollis eu risus, fermentum volutpat maecenas convallis etiam, et eget ut aliquet phasellus sagittis metus. Nulla vel wisi a eu in. Diam sociis eros.         Aliquet vitae commodo ante, rutrum praesent odio urna pellentesque. Metus viverra volutpat etiam lorem nesciunt, sapien pellentesque, massa nec. Nec congue aliquam a lobortis sed, dui imperdiet vestibulum magnis aenean sed sit, dignissim sem sodales.
                            </p>
                        </article>
                    
                        <article class="Tweets">
                            <h2>Tweets</h2>
                            <h3>A list apart finally goes responsive</h3>
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, posuere erat quis tellus, pede non maecenas convallis dapibus ut, ipsum arcu facilisi nunc mollis eu risus, fermentum volutpat maecenas convallis etiam, et eget ut aliquet phasellus sagittis metus. Nulla vel wisi a eu in. Diam sociis eros.         Aliquet vitae commodo ante, rutrum praesent odio urna pellentesque. Metus viverra volutpat etiam lorem nesciunt, sapien pellentesque, massa nec. Nec congue aliquam a lobortis sed, dui imperdiet vestibulum magnis aenean sed sit, dignissim sem sodales.
                            </p>

                            <h3>A list apart finally goes responsive</h3>
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, posuere erat quis tellus, pede non maecenas convallis dapibus ut, ipsum arcu facilisi nunc mollis eu risus, fermentum volutpat maecenas convallis etiam, et eget ut aliquet phasellus sagittis metus. Nulla vel wisi a eu in. Diam sociis eros.         Aliquet vitae commodo ante, rutrum praesent odio urna pellentesque. Metus viverra volutpat etiam lorem nesciunt, sapien pellentesque, massa nec. Nec congue aliquam a lobortis sed, dui imperdiet vestibulum magnis aenean sed sit, dignissim sem sodales.
                            </p>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                    

                </div>
                <!-----End of Content --->

                <footer>
                    <p>&copy; Buko Ogbobe Responsive Start File</p>
                </footer>

            </div> <!----end of Container ---->
        </div> <!----end of Wrapper ---->        

    </body>
```

[image]

Comment: If the only time you see the blue background is behind the UL, could you remove the blue background from the wrapper and apply it to the UL?

Comment: Thanks James, i did think about doing that as a last resort, but i would prefer to understand why that background is showing for block level elements taking up the full width of their containing elements

Answer (score 0):

Here's two solutions, you can use :

```
footer {
    margin-top:-13px;
}
```

or :

```
#content article.Tweets, article.Tweets p {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

This will fix the gap in between your footer and content.

Comment: Thanks Lindow, the problem is, i still want the margin from the article tag, just so that there is a white space between the footer and the content. But i'm also abit lost as to why it is happening, they are all block level elements taking up the full width of the content div..i would expect they just stack up without leaving any space unless you add a margin which i did. but in my case the margin i set isn't working correctly because the background color of the content div shouldn't be showing if its following the normal content flow

Comment: You should add the white space inbetween the footer and content using padding-bottom on the `#content` instead of using the background gap.